# Does Google Maps have a Map Tile API like HERE Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Does Google Maps have a tile API to receive meta information about buildings?

For example: HERE Maps offers a tile API to obtain information about buildings. But data is mainly only in cities available. See: [Here Map Tile API](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/example-meta-combine.html#example-meta-combine__user-story-metainfo-extruded).

A response from the HERE Map Tile API looks like this:

```
{ "metadata" : {
"street labels":[ { "name":"Danziger Straße", "font size":"13", "vertices": [ 38.21, -18.57, 79.17, 4.82, 88.82, 10.34, 121.50, 30.46 ] } ],
"labels":[{ "name": "111", "type":"TEXT", "bounding boxes": [ { "annotation  box":[ 146.69, 139.41, 26.62, 16.75 ] } ] }],
"city center labels":[],
"buildings":[ { "id": "1609441356716643099", "sectors": [ { "info": { "bottom height": 0, "height": 6.125 }, "vertices": [ 248, 138.69, 243, 146.91, 231, 174.84, 256, 189.18, 256, 142.78, 219, 197.88, 125, 82.78, 99, 132.09 ], "polygons": [ [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [ 5, 2, 1, 6, 7]], "outlines": [ [ 2, 5, 7, 6, 1, 0, 4 ], [ 3, 2 ]] } ] } ],
"transit stops":[  ],
"POIs":[  ]
}
```

The metadata can be used to tell a few things about the building such as length, etc.

Google Maps is able draw buildings on all places see here: [Buildings](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Jagdfeldring+45,+85540+Haar/@48.1043871,11.7187575,18.54z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x479de1ebdb2c2be5:0x6e53811c0d5379c7!8m2!3d48.10379!4d11.72376) (Countryside).

But how would I be able to obtain those meta information?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We made the same questions many times and finally we had a response to it. There is a new API launch by Google that you can use in very special cases and you have to justify the use of it. Here is the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile/#tile_requests

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you very much! This API was not available when I asked the question in October '16. Hopefully it will provide detailed information about buildings (or at least in future), I'm gonna check it out soon.

Comment: They have discontinued the Tile API.

Comment: Is there any alternative map tile service from Google or it still out of support for public usage?