# How do I enable Google Maps Tile API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-map-tiles-api

I found out from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070304/does-google-maps-have-a-map-tile-api-like-here-maps) that there is a Google Maps Tile API (official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile/)).
However, I can't seem to find a way to enable this API.

Except for the link found in the question mentioned above, I couldn't find any other reference to this API, anywhere. It's not even listed on the [main page of the Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) (here) or the [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/).

The API is also not listed in the Developer Console API Library.

I've tried sending a session request ([as explained in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile/#session_token_request)) but received this response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Maps Tile API has not been used in project XXXXXXXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/tile.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXXXXXXXXXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/tile.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXXXXXXXXXX"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Maps Tile API has not been used in project XXXXXXXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/tile.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXXXXXXXXXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
 }
}
```

Following the link to the Developer Console, I receive this message:

> The API "tile.googleapis.com" doesn't exist or you don't have
>   permission to access it

Is this a Google Maps premium feature? Does any one have more information on this API?

Comment: FYI: Google Map Tiles API at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile is now generally available for Preview, including access to 2D and 3D tiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Tile API is not available for Standard plan users. Neither for Premium plan users [1]. It requires a special license. You should contact Google's [sales team](https://developers.google.com/maps/contact-sales/) directly in order to get some additional information regarding Tile API.

[1] https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/overview#package

Comment: I would send the maps API tech support a message about using the Tile API for development purposes to begin with.https://support.google.com/googleapi/contact/maps_api_tech_support

Comment: I contacted Google Maps Sales Team. The response was negative. Tiles API is deprecated and cannot be licensed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The Google [Map Tiles API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile) is now generally available for Preview, including access to 2D and 3D tiles.
Please note use of this API is subject to the [Google Maps Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms) and [Map Tiles API Policies](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile/policies).