# google search results map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

Does anyone know where this API is located in google maps api?

For example when you search for `Romania` map, the image is generated using this url:

http://google.com//maps/vt/data=CymDFzaC0_-n-R3wmlVpuTk5Nvkj9oiS4wHQIRmxHss_3EIdRwV9pa4wLsltatzity9XmE9Y48yR_uDhKzGBJXP5asS7UoJluFoeXIM65UiTJGrw5TcWafd5UJMl2HePi-FjsZL48JsTbDJ9gr8tP9ghU80SCnx49lZEqpejUX90AttSZpkR-xd1vFkCzU1URVWPhI0fjp7dxrDIm8ZhGbWeAoOT3Z8

I tried looking up `vt/data=` but have not been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Google doesn't expose an API to get direct access to map tiles imagery for Standard plan users.

Even more, the Terms of Service of Google Maps APIs prohibits the direct access to tiles imagery via any undocumented interface. Have a look at paragraph 10.1 (a) of Terms of Service, it reads

> **No access to APIs or Content except through the Service.** You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service. For example, you **must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s)**.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?#10-license-restrictions

Also, based on the following answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41703936/5140781

I can say that Google has a new Tile API, but it requires a special Premium plan license and it is not available for Standard plan users.

I hope my answer addresses your doubt.

Comment: Thanks for clarification